# Open CV image saving in smaller size without compressions

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

The question i have is the following:
I have a camera( with resolution Resolution : 640 x 480 px) and I get an image from that camera (I get an 8 bit/ pixel grayscale image) after the image acquisition I save the image in a bmp format. My code is the followig :

`Mat img2(640,480,CV_8UC1,0)`;

`cap.read(img2);`

`bool succes = imwrite("D:\\TestImage3.bmp",img2);`

`if(!succes){`

`cout << "Failed to save the image";`
`return -1;`
`}`

`namedWindow("myWindow",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);`

`imshow("myWindow",img2);`

The saved image is very large almost 1 MB and i want a smaller image without losing any information (without compresing the image)???

The second question on this topic is:
even if the image is gray some times I still get some rgb noise, its like I would have set a 3 channel setting instead of 1 channel setting for my image

If anyone knows the answer please let me know, I would be very grateful
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can save your image as `PNG` which is an lossless image compression format.

```
bool succes = imwrite("D:\\TestImage3.png",img2);
```

Comment: You are all right the use of png transforms an image to a smaller size, and it seems the clarity is kept

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting one of the Answers (I think that all solved your problem ;) so that other can see that you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

With the cv::imwrite function you can pass additional parameters depending on the image format.
PNG is a lossless image format but you can still chose the level of compression for example :

```
Mat img2;
cap.read(img2);
cvtColor(img2, img2, CV_BGR2GRAY); // Convert to single channel

vector<int> compression_params;
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
compression_params.push_back(9);

bool succes = imwrite("D:\\TestImage3.bmp", img2, compression_params);
if(!succes)
{
    cout << "Failed to save the image"; return -1; 
}

imshow("myWindow",img2);
waitKey(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the default constructor for Mat with no params.

```
Mat img2;
cap.read(img2);
cvtColor(img2, img2, CV_BGR2GRAY); // Convert to single channel
bool succes = imwrite("D:\\TestImage3.bmp", img2);
if(!succes)
{
    cout << "Failed to save the image"; return -1; 
}

imshow("myWindow",img2);
waitKey(0);
```

Also, bmp is known for its large uncompressed size. Use .png instead.